# Interpreting HASH JOIN in Oracle query plan

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

When I see something like this in an Oracle query plan:

```
HASH JOIN
    TABLE1
    TABLE2
```

Which of these two tables is being [hashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join)?

The Oracle documentation refers to a "smaller" table usually being hashed, but is there a guarantee that the hashed table will always be in a particular position (either top or bottom sub-node) when displayed inside a query plan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Example 9-3 Hash Joins*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL94688), in the JOIN documentation, concerns an explain plan for hash joins. There is a sentence under the example which states:

> In a hash join, the data set for the hash table always appears first in the list of operations (Step 2).

One remark; Oracle doesn't hash a smaller table, but a smaller dataset.